# I can not find specific cron running at *:21 and *:56 on Debian

Tags: linux, unix, cron, debian, crontab

I am frustrated. I have two mystic crons running on our server, that I can not find by doing crontab -l. The good thing is these crons are sending mails. That is how I know those are running at :21m and :56m every hour.

I have root access and I have also been looking into /etc/cron.daily and /etc/cron.hourly.

Nothing.

Am I totally blinded?

Comment: Could somebody be `ssh`ing in from another host at those times?

Answer (score 1):

The standard place for user crontabs is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`.  Overall, I would check these locations:

- `/etc/crontab`
- `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, `/etc/cron.monthly`
- `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Depending on your OS distro, `~/.crontab` may also be in effect.

Comment: also /etc/cron.d